# preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, rotation, orientation

I am trying to programatically force one popover View to be landscape, whilst i set the device orientation of the app to be portrait in the project settings.
My code looks like this:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft
}
```

This didnt work so i tried adding:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
}
```

But still no rotation. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The only time a view controller gets a say in rotation is when it is either the *root* view controller or a *full-screen presented* view controller. Your view controller (a popover) is neither; therefore it gets no say in rotation.

Comment: It is presented as a popover. Is that my issue?

Comment: Yes. How could a mere popover change the orientation of the whole app.

Comment: Maybe i worded my question incorrectly. I want only the popover view to be landscape, the rest of the app should remain with a portrait orientation

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. The popover has no "orientation". You can try to dictate its _shape_ so that it is wider than tall, though you might not succeed...